# How can I give an image two rounded corners?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Is there a way to crop an image to a certain shape using javascript?

Comment: Define "certain shape". Rectangular? Circular? A polygon?

Comment: rectangular with two rounded corners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier if you use an image stencil.

Your image stencil has a transparent shape like the one your looking for, rectangular with two rounded corners.  The rest of the stencil makes up the frame area.

You display the image, then display the image stencil.

Comment: There is no special code.  You display your image, then display the image stencil on top of the image using absolute positioning.  It's easier if the image and the image stencil are the same size.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm envisioning what you are describing correctly. Are you assuming a solid-color background (or underlay) and then "knocking out" the corners of the image by overlaying the same color on top?

Comment: @Phrogz: If the frame of the image stencil is the same color as the web page background, then yes, the frame "disappears" into the web page background.  If the frame of the image stencil is a different color than the web page background, you get a shape (the transparent part of the image stencil showing the underlying image) surrounded by a frame (the opaque part of the image stencil).  Either effect is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using `border-radius` on an `img` element works on Safari v5, Chrome v8, and FF v4b. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GXNVF/2/

It does not work on FF v3.x, even with the non-standard `-moz-border-radius` properties. I don't have Windows to test, but according to [this page](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) it should work on IE9.

**Edit**: Here's an update example, based on @Spudley's point, showing that with a background image you can make it work in FF v3.x:
http://jsfiddle.net/GXNVF/3/

Further, also per @Spudley, you can use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) to make it work for IE6-8. *(This uses IE's CSS behaviors and requires you to add one extra CSS rule and host the `htc` file they supply on your site.)*

Comment: it does *kinda* work in Firefox 3... the rounded borders are set, but the box content (ie the image) isn't cropped. If you used a background-image instead of an img tag, then it would be cropped.

Comment: Also, border-radius can be made to work in older versions of IE (6,7,8), using [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com).